# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection' not found

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I installed php amqp extension with `pecl install amqp`, and added `extension=amqp.so` into the php.ini. But I still get an error when execute the [code from rabbitmq's tutorial](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/php/send.php). What's wrong?

```
[root@VM_67_229_centos rabbit_mq_test]# php phpinfo.php  | grep amqp
PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /data/roxma/rabbit_mq_test/phpinfo.php on line 2
amqp
amqp.auto_ack => 0 => 0
amqp.channel_max => 256 => 256
amqp.connect_timeout => 0 => 0
amqp.frame_max => 131072 => 131072
amqp.heartbeat => 0 => 0
amqp.host => localhost => localhost
amqp.login => guest => guest
amqp.password => guest => guest
amqp.port => 5672 => 5672
amqp.prefetch_count => 3 => 3
amqp.read_timeout => 0 => 0
amqp.timeout => no value => no value
amqp.vhost => / => /
amqp.write_timeout => 0 => 0

[root@VM_67_229_centos rabbit_mq_test]# php send.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection' not found in /data/roxma/rabbit_mq_test/send.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I fugured I just got confused between [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) and PHP's [amqp extension](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.amqp.php)

AMQPStreamConnection is not part of php's amqp extension  :(